# How to add different click events on each pie of a pie chart created by highcharts usin jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

On clicking each slice of a pie chart, I need to link it to another html page which would give more information about that particular slice.

Comment: Bind the Click event on the PlotOptions to a Javascript function, and on this function you can find out which point received the click.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: Can you provide me a sample click event function to link to different html pages by clicking each slice of the pie chart?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like that:

```
plotOptions: { pie: { point: { events: { click: PieClick } } } }
```

...

```
function PieClick() {
    var sliceClicked = this.name;

    // do something
}
```

Comment: I just tried in the way that you have mentioned but the click didnt seems to work, Can you suggest me whats I go wrong here,

Comment: plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        }
                    },
     events: {
      click: function() { 
       showpage();
 
      }
     }
                }
            }

Comment: and following are the slice names that i use

Comment: useseries: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Application share',
                data: [
                    ['Server Appn',   45.0],
                    ['Anti-Virus Appn',       15.0],
                    {
                        name: 'System Appn',
                        y: 12.0,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Network Appn',    8.0],
                    ['Android Appn',     11.0],
                    ['Other Appn',   9.0]
                ]
            }]

Comment: This bit function() { showpage(); } should be function() { showpage }

Answer (score 3):

I just tried the following simple method which helped me to get the solution.

The plotOption can be like following,

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        point: {
                            events: {
                                    click: function() {
                                            location.href = this.options.url;
                                        }
                                }

            }
    }
}
```

and in the series you can use something like this,

```
series: [{
            data: [{
               name: sample 1,
               y: 29.9,
               url: 'http://bing.com/search?q=foo'
            }, {
                name: sample 2,
                y: 71.5,
                url: 'http://bing.com/search?q=bar'
            }, {
                name: sample 2,
                y: 106.4,
                url: 'http://bing.com/search?q=foo+bar'
            }]        
        }]
```

View the example in the following link,

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click-url/